# Xorg.conf isn't saving?

Tags: nvidia, display

So I installed the proper Nvidia drivers for my graphics card and modified the screen to a personalized resolution and size because my "monitor" isn't actually a monitor and therefore isn't made to fit typical computer resolutions for some reason.

Anyway, I clicked the "create xorg.conf" button or whatever it is and put the file in `/etc/X11`. However this hasn't seemed to work.

Everytime I boot my computer in Ubuntu the resolution remains the default one which is off. The only way to fix this if for me to open the Nvidia control panel and manually change the resolution back to what it should be. Why does this keep happening? I suspect that it might have to do with the fact that `xorg.conf` file's name changes ever so often. It will change to something like `xorg.conf.8125408` or some other random number and i'm not sure why. Does anyone know of a fix?

I have tried search for answers but all I find are questions as to where the `xorg.conf` file is and not my exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe related to the GPU manager. It should be mentionned in the log file `/var/log/gpu-manager.log`.

If so, try commenting out the first 4 lines of the file `/etc/init/gpu-manager.conf`.

```
#start on (starting lightdm
#          or starting kdm
#          or starting xdm
#          or starting lxdm)
task
exec gpu-manager --log /var/log/gpu-manager.log
```

Comment: I just checked the log file, and to be honest i'm not entirely sure what I'm looking at, however I saw something really interesting. I have Nvidia installed, however it claims that it is not enabled. Perhaps that's why it's ignoring the xorg.conf?

Answer (score 0):

What about saving it in /usr/share/X11/ ? I know I have to save config files there instead of /etc/X11 on my system for certain configs.